# How to use PHP variables with SELECT and INSERT INTO SQL Statements

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, insert-into

Below is the code i'm trying to get to work:

```
    $y= "SELECT ('PRV_IDX')
         FROM LLS_PRIVILEGES
         WHERE `PRV_NAME` = 'Reader';";

     mysql_query($y);

$x= "SELECT ('USER_IDX')
     FROM LLS_USERS
     WHERE `USR_LOGIN` = '".$_SESSION['tool_user']."';";

      mysql_query($x);

$w= "INSERT INTO LLS_USERS_PRIVILEGES
     (USP_USR_IDX,USP_PRV_IDX)
     VALUES ($x,$y);    ";

     mysql_query($w);
```

I want to insert these values from the select statements into the final table. However, I am not sure if my Syntax is correct and I have been unable to find a solution online. I wasn't sure if you had to do the mysql_query each time for the select statement to actually take hold in and place it in the $variable.

Sorry, I'm new to SQL, but thank you for the help!

Comment: Please do _not_ use the deprecated `mysql_` functions, use `mysqli_` functions or PDO instead.

Comment: You did not find any examples for usage of sql and php online? I cannot believe this. Every snippet of php using a relational database is a perfect example for how to do that.

Comment: Have a look at this http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Answer (score -1):

**mysql_*** functions are deprecated. Use **PDO** instead :

```
$y=$dbh->query("SELECT ('PRV_IDX')
    FROM LLS_PRIVILEGES
    WHERE `PRV_NAME` = 'Reader'");
$x=$dbh->prepare("SELECT ('USER_IDX')
     FROM LLS_USERS
     WHERE `USR_LOGIN` = ?");
$x->execute(array($_SESSION['tool_user']));
$w=$dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO LLS_USERS_PRIVILEGES
     (USP_USR_IDX,USP_PRV_IDX)
     VALUES (?,?)");
$y="SELECT ('PRV_IDX')
    FROM LLS_PRIVILEGES
    WHERE `PRV_NAME` = 'Reader'";
$x="SELECT ('USER_IDX')
     FROM LLS_USERS
     WHERE `USR_LOGIN` = '".$_SESSION['tool_user']."'");
$w->execute(array($x,$y));
```

More About **PDO** : http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to use prepared statements for the first query. For the second one it depends.

Comment: Why do you redeclare the variables $y=... and $x=... after you have already queried or prepared and executed $y and $x respectively?
Still having trouble making it work

Comment: Your code in the question is inserting the queries executed in $x and $y to **LLS_USERS_PRIVILEGES**, so I made the answer like that.

Comment: Yes but once you've made the query/execute, can't you just go straight from $w = $dbh-> ... to $w->execute(array($x,$y));?
What do those two lines of restating/declaring $x and $y do that the first 3 lines of code not do?

Comment: The first 2 $x and $y returns 0 or some other value, so that insertion into **LLS_USERS_PRIVILEGES** will be 0 or 1. To get the real **SQL** query to be inserted, we have to redefine the query and append it's values. But the redefined $x and $y queries won't execute.